# How to call static HTML files

Tags: go

I created a static folder that contains `index.html` file, and in my go file, I wrote:

```golang
package main

import (
    "net/http"
)

func main() {
    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))

    http.ListenAndServe(":8482", nil)
}
```

And it works fine upon exploring `http://localhost:8482/`

I tried to write the code as:

```golang
http.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))
```

But it fails upon exploring `http://localhost:8482/static` with 404 error

[image]

Comment: Try: `http://localhost:8482/static/` - `/` at the end

Comment: @Vusal same thing :(

Comment: Is the `static` folder in the current directory, from where you launch your app? Also try an absolute path.

Comment: @HasanAYousef I tried your code and it works. Probably the directory path is not correct

Comment: @icza i added screen shoot showing my full path

Comment: @Vusal I added screen shoot showing my full path

Comment: Change the router registration to: `http.Handle("/static/", http.FileServer...` so it handles all sub routes & not just `/static`.

Comment: @colm.anseo same thing :(

Comment: maybe you can check this: https://medium.com/rungo/beginners-guide-to-serving-files-using-http-servers-in-go-4e542e628eac - he is doing in a little bit different way

Comment: Thanks @Vusal it is working now, by using `http.StripPrefix`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`http.Handle("/static", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static")))` simply means, "whenever someone connects to `.../static`, reroute the entire request to a file server rooted at directory ./static".

However, the url is passed along to the file server as-is. In other words, the file server receives the request from the user, and believes that the user is looking for a file called "static" within the root `("./static")` directory.

In fact, if you simply placed a file called "static" in your "`./static`" directory, going to `.../static` would serve that file.

So the fix requires two things:

1. Change the path prefix to "`/static/`" rather than "`/static`", so that all files within the static directory can be rerouted to the file server (rather than only the "/static" request)
2. Strip the "`/static/`" path prefix from the request before passing it to the file server.

Like so:

```
http.Handle("/static/", http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static"))))
```

Comment: There is another example on the golang http documentation here: https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#example_FileServer_stripPrefix